# Lorenz gauge and residual gauge freedom

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, potential, gauge

I have this 4-potential: $A^\mu= a^\mu e^{ik^\alpha x_\alpha}$

Working in the Lorenz gauge, it is known that we can still make a transformation of this kind

$$
A'^\mu = A^\mu + \partial ^\mu \theta
\tag{1}$$
with
$$
 \Box\, \theta = 0
\tag{2}$$

Now since $\Box \theta=0$ we have that

$$
\theta = f_0 e^{ik^\alpha x_\alpha} + f_0^* e^{-ik^\alpha x_\alpha}
\tag{3}$$

Where $*$ denotes the complex conjugate.

We then rewrite $(1)$ in this form

$$
A'^\mu= a'^\mu e^{ik^\alpha x_\alpha} = a^\mu e^{ik^\alpha x_\alpha} + ik^\mu f_0 e^{ik^\alpha x_\alpha} - ik^\mu f_0^* e^{-ik^\alpha x_\alpha}
\tag{4}$$

Now in my notes it says that the last term in the RHS of $(4)$ must be $0$ if we want the equation to hold for every $x^\alpha$, thus  we obtain

$$
a'^\mu  = a^\mu + ik^\mu f_0
\tag{5}$$

Now what I don't get is the condition that last term should vanish, why is that? I just don't get it. The textbook I have, instead, doesn't even put the complex conjugate term in the equation $(3)$ solution of $(2)$ and then it obtains $(5)$ without that condition i'm struggling to understand. It makes sense to me, but then another question arises: why leaving out the complex conjugate term at the beginning?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Equations (3) and (4) do not match up; it seems that either there should be a minus sign in the exponent of the $f_0^*$ term in both (3) and (4), or in (4) there should be no minus sign.  Also, which textbook (and which specific pages) are you referring to?

Comment: In fact, dare to put the complex conjugate term at the beginning. Do eq. (4) again with the added c.c. term. No term has to vanish. One can assume that terms complex conjugate to each other are independent. Then you get result (5) and the complex conjugate of (5).  Both results mean the same: Namely $a'^{\mu}=a^{\mu}+ik^{\mu}f_0$ which is the wanted result. BTW: diracula is right with the sign in the exponent of c.c.term of $\theta$ which has to also put at the same place in eq.(4).

Comment: @diracula yeah you are right I corrected it. The book i'm referring to is [Barone-Relatività](https://www.amazon.it/Relatività-Principi-applicazioni-Vincenzo-Barone/dp/8833957578) page 357.

Comment: @FredericThomas Ok so, if I'm understanding correctly i have two results :$(5)$ and its complex conjugate and I'm just using one of those results?

Comment: The reason is the sign in the exponential of the last term. $\exp(ik^\mu x_\mu)$ and $\exp(-ik^\mu x_\mu)$ are linearly independent (in the function space) and therefore the coefficients need to vanish separately. This gives two equations: $f_0^*=0$ and $a'^\mu=a^\mu+ik^\mu f_0$. I wonder, however, how $f_0$ can be non-zero if $f_0^*$ is zero...

Comment: @Run like hell: yes. Because one result is the complex conjugate of the other. Differently said: Take complex conjugate of the second result on RHS and LHS and you get the first result. Result (2)does not contain really new information.

Comment: @FredericThomas thank you, now it's clearer, now I see that it was banal but sometimes I get lots in these things.  Thanks again. Have a good day